# retrieve PHP post values in submit using jquery

Tags: php, jquery, forms

I want to retrieve post values in php in jquery form, so as to submit the form using jquery. I am using jquery.submit() function to submit my form. Example is as below

```
$('#form').submit(function{
   var data = '//post variables from php script here';
   $.ajax({
    type:'post',
    data:data,
    url://url to save the data,
    success:function(response){
       //success message here;
    }
});
```

Can anyone please help me?

Comment: You should clarify your question, as seen below we don't know if you want to access POST variables in your JS code or serialize all form data and retrive it in your PHP script.

Comment: @TomaszBanasiak: I have to serialize and retrieve data in php script

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly what you want to do, but as far as I can see it seems that you need **json_encode** php function.

```
var data = '<?php echo json_encode($_POST)?>';
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot directly extract POST variables in JavaScript - which you can with GET since they are part of the URL (?my_get_variable=is_here etc.)

If you really NEED to have access to your POST variables in JavaScript, what you could do is make some PHP iterating over and printing out the post variables. The following code fills a JavaScript array called PostVariables with the post variables passed to your page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var postVariables = new Array();
    <?php foreach($_POST as $key => $value): ?>
    postVariables['<?=$key?>'] = '<?=$value?>';
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</script>
```

If your POST body is name=John&pet=Cat&friends=Many, you will get the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     var postVariables = new Array();
     postVariables['name'] = 'John';
     postVariables['pet'] = 'Cat';
     postVariables['friends'] = 'Many';
</script>
```

Of course, this does require PHP.

If you need the data in that format, just adapt the script:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
     var myData = "";
    <?php foreach($_POST as $key => $value): ?>
    myData += "<?=$key?>=<?=$value?>&";
    <?php endforeach; ?> 
 </script>
```

Comment: But forces you to use JSON format which would not be what this guy's looking for right here it seems. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can post form data with `serialize`. Example form:

```
<form id="myForm" method="POST">
    <input name="one" value="11" />
    <input name="two" value="22" />
    <input id="submit" type="submit" value="11" />
</form>

<div id="test"></div>
```

Javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$('#submit').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); 
    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        data: $("#myForm").serialize(),
        url:'mypage.php',
        success:function(response){
           $("#test").html(response);
        }
    });
});

</script>
```

mypage.php

```
<?php  var_dump($_POST); ?>
```

#### output

```
array (size=2)
  'one' => string '11' (length=2)
  'two' => string '22' (length=2)
```

Comment: I tried with the solution but my php script when print_r $_POST and if "element" is form element name then i get the values as array([0]=>e,[1]=>l.....)

Answer (score 0):

Solved myself. Had been using the plugin jquery form on my site. Implemented the form submit using same.
http://malsup.com/jquery/form/#ajaxForm